Soundtrack of Phantom of the Paradise
I am looking for the complete soundtrack of Brian de Palma's Phantom of the Paradise. The original soundtrack by Paul Williams can be found easily, but I remember a few times in the movie that classical music (in particular piano music) can be heard, and it's not on the album. Do you know what it is?

Are you looking for the album/compilation or the soundtrack itself? Note that song identification is off-topic.
